# Client-Server - Identical model

Tags: java, client-server

Me and some people at school are building a calendar appointment and meeting system as a project. The case is as following:

> Every employee in a business has it's own "calendar" with meetings and appointments. They can of course add these, and invite other employees to meetings and so on. The model consists of about 5-6 different classes. Each client will connect to a server (which saves the data to a database). When a change is done in the model on a client. The model on the server has to get updated, and updated on every other connected client.

The general question is as following: **What should we do to make sure every connected client to the server, and the server as well, has the same updated model?**

Hopefully I have made myself clear :) (Edit: I did not :)

**EDIT:
The server and the clients should have the exact same model. Can I transfer multiple objects through sockets? If the objects were to be transferred as text, what is the best way to do it so the objects could be set up correctly at the server or the clients?**

Answer (score 2):

To me, the first statement contradicts the last statement somewhat. It is saying:

> Every employee has it's own calendar with meetings and appointments.

Which to me, says that just because I have a meeting at 10:00am on Monday, doesn't mean everyone else should have that meeting too, unless I invite them. So, there would be no reason to send that information to all clients when they shouldn't have visibility of it; which it seems the last statement is saying:

> The model on the server has to get updated, and updated on every other connected client.

I would split up your model into `business` (assuming you support multiple businesses), `employee (client)`, `calendar`, `event (meeting/appointment)`, and anything else relevant.

You would need to make sure the client's own calendar is synced with the server obviously and get that working first. You will then want to have an event that is handled where Employee A has asked Employee B to attend a meeting, which will need to send Employee B an invite for their acceptance/decline to the meeting which can then be updated on the server and then replicated to the clients who are interested.

I would implement this as a pull model rather than a push model (in the spirit of traditional implementations) where the client "polls" the server every `x` interval to ask for the latest information for their calendar. Any changes they make are pushed back to the server, and the server then updates the database as needed.

This means that you can keep everything synchronised happily on the server and when a client asks for the latest information, the server just sends it back to them and then the client updates as necessary.

This way the server can handle any synchronisation issues with events by returning notifications where synchronisation issues occur. Think for example: if Employee B accepts a meeting, and then Employee A cancels the meeting before all clients are synchronised. You can just send a notification back to Employee B saying that, without having to worry that all clients are in the same state.

Hope this helps.

::**Edit** (based on question edit)::

You might want to check out [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and how to implement it. I would create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) that encapsulates the data you want to send and then serialize it and send it to the client. The client deserializes the data into the object(s) it needs to use. Think of it like an envelope that will group your objects together and send them to the client when it needs it.

As for the requirement to have all clients be able to see all calendars, I think the same basic principles apply. Have the client ask the server for the calendars, then have the server return a payload which contains the necessary data for the client.

Comment: Quick comment: A user should be able to view other users calendars